> Could not find org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.2
A problem occurred configuring root project 'primevideoapp'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not find org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.2.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/modules/http-builder/http-builder/0.7.2/http-builder-0.7.2.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/modules/http-builder/http-builder/0.7.2/http-builder-0.7.2.pom
- https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/codehaus/groovy/modules/http-builder/http-builder/0.7.2/http-builder-0.7.2.pom
Required by:
project : > com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3

Possible solution:

Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

how do i fix this issue

Please have a look at [ask] and how to create [mcve]. http-builder:0.7.2 does not exist. Could you post the details of your pom.xml?

Also use [code block] format for logs and errors.
